# Detecting Bluetooth Headphones Key Press Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetoothheadset

I am trying to detect key presses of the Bluetooth headset. Overriding onKeyDown and dispatchKeyEvent methods can detect normal headphones presses but not the Bluetooth ones. The other questions related to this topic are from ages ago, so they are not useful because of deprecated methods, etc.

Comment: Are you a media app that is currently playing something?

Comment: actually yes, I use MediaPlayer class to play audio and want to react to the Bluetooth key presses @ianhanniballake

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons)?

Comment: Yes, I did. Documentation recommends using FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS which is deprecated. @ianhanniballake